Thermodynamics, change in entropy
One mole of an ideal gas expands reversibly from a temperature of 25 ° C and 1 atm to a temperature of 0 ° C and pressure of 0.65 atm. Calculate ΔS. Assume that Cv = 3/2R.
I solved this using the formula: ds=cp ln t1/t2 + R lnp2/p1 at last step I got a doubt that what should be the value of R

It’s $$n\text{C}_p ln(\frac{\text{T}_2}{\text{T}_1})$$ not the other way around. And your R value should be in joules per mole kelvin (so R = 8.314J/molK) as entropy is usually preferred in J/K.

For an ideal gas, the equation for entropy change is $$\Delta S=nC_p\ln{(T_2/T_1)}-nR\ln{(P_2/P_1)}$$This equation applies to both reversible and irreversible changes.
